# What does new uint8_t(64) do? Do POD types have constructors?

Tags: c++

I made a mistake in a code. I wrote something like:

```
uint8_t * var = new uint8_t(64);
```

instead of:

```
uint8_t * var = new uint8_t[64];
```

The compiler (gcc) did not complain, but at execution, I get a `SEGFAULT` with this message:

```
... free(): invalid next size (fast): ...
```

Running with valgrind (memchecker): I get the following diagnostic:
   `Invalid write of size 8`

I tried this with gcc 4.7.2, producing a 64-bit executable, running on Linux. I also tried with gcc 4.5.2, producing a 32-bit executable and I get the same kind of issue and diagnostic.

It looks like some memory gets allocated, but not the amount indicated between the parenthesis.

What did I actually do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
uint8_t * var = new uint8_t(64); // dynamically allocated one uint8_t object, and
                                 // initialize to 64

uint8_t * var = new uint8_t[64]; // dynamically allocate space for
                                //  64 uint8_t objects (no initialization)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet initialises *one* `uint8_t` object with the value 64. The second initialises an array of sixty-four uninitialised `uint8_t` objects.

Comment: `uint8_t` is just typedef for `unsigned char`, at least in libstdc++. What's the huss with object?

Comment: @jnovacho in that case you can read that as "(...) initialises one `unsigned char` object (...) uninitialised `unsigned char` objects" if you prefer. It's the same thing.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I would refer to `unsigned char`/`uint8_t` as primitive, not as object. Because it's not class instance.

Comment: This question is not tagged Java. `unsigned char` is a fundamental type; it is also an object type. Most types are object types (exceptions this include reference types and function types)

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation. I'm more used to Java terminology.

Comment: @jnovacho for completeness, C++ uses "class types" for what you were thinking of (or maybe "polymorphic types" if you thought of things with virtual; "class types" includes simple things like `struct foo { int x; };`)